# Variable does not exist: CurrentElement in batch class

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

[image]

I'm trying to insert data from standard FlowInterview object to Custom object.

But it is throwing error like below for all fieds mapping.

Below is my code

```
public class FlowInterviewHandler implements Database.Batchable<sObject> { 

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) { 

     return Database.getQueryLocator(             'SELECT CreatedById,CreatedDate,CurrentElement,FlowVersionViewId,Guid,Id,InterviewLabel,InterviewStatus,IsDeleted,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,Name,OwnerId,PauseLabel,WasPausedFromScreen from FlowInterview'         ); 

    }    

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){  

 // process each batch of records         

List<Flow_Interview__c> Flowrecords = new List<Flow_Interview__c>();         

for (FlowInterview Fl : scope) {             

Flow_Interview__c flc = new Flow_Interview__c();              

flc.CurrentElement__c = Fl.CurrentElement;             

flc.Guid__c = Fl.Guid;             

flc.Id__c = Fl.Id;             

flc.InterviewLabel__c = Fl.InterviewLabel;             

flc.InterviewStatus__c = Fl.InterviewStatus;             

flc.PauseLabel__c = Fl.PauseLabel;             

flc.WasPausedFromScreen__c = Fl.WasPausedFromScreen;                          

Flowrecords.add(flc);                                   

}         

Insert Flowrecords;     

}               

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){              

} 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic `sObject` can only access the Id field. You'll want to change:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){
```

To:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<FlowInterview> scope){
```

This should fix all your compilation issues.

Comment: Hi, i've changed now I'm getting the below error  
at line 1 : Class FlowInterviewHandler must implement the method: void Database.Batchable<SObject>.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List<SObject>)

at line 8: global methods do not support parameter type of List<flowinterview>
line 8 is execute method.  If I chnage the object from FlowInterview to other object like Account then it is not showing any error.

Comment: @Suri Your methods should be public, not global.

Comment: Changed to public but same error.
Class FlowInterviewHandler must implement the method: void Database.Batchable<SObject>.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List<SObject>)

Comment: @Suri You don't happen to have a class in your org called FlowInterview, do you? That would cause many of the problems you seem to be having. Try `List<Schema.FlowInterview>` instead.

Comment: Thank you! List<Schema.FlowInterview> this solved the issue.